# MySQL Database Showing Different Permissions

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

We are working with an older version of MySQL (v5.1.35) and recently we provisioned a new server to replace our aging machine. After doing some test database restores I noticed that there were a couple of permissions missing from one database but not the other. These two missing permissions are affecting the functionality of the site and so far I am at a loss as to where to find them.

Even though I restored the exact same database backup to two separate databases, one has the EVENT and TRIGGER permissions available, and the other does not.

[image: permissions missing?]

As you can see the permissions are not even available for me to assign! However on another db I created from the same dumpfile the permissions ARE avaialble...

[image: but they are here]

I am not sure if its just something with the way I am restoring or what. So far I have tried dropping and re-creating the database but that did not work. I am trying another restore to a database with a different name to see if that works.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you know how to work with the mysql command line? tools can be and have been known to have issues/bugs

Comment: command line extensions were not installed on this server. I have been trying to use other SQL tools like SQLyog. That tool shows me the permissions but keeps telling me permission denied when I try to change them. I know the account credentials i have are correct.

Comment: The account that you are using may not have with grant options...that is why u cannot Change them..

Comment: Yeah that is what is killing me, I am using 'root' with the proper creds and still getting access denied. Not sure why

Comment: run `show grants for 'root'@'localhost';` in query editor and post what it returns...by default root should have with grant option, so something doesnt make sense...